# TFS 2015 - Fields Not Loading

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are experiencing an intermittent problem in TFS 2015 (Update 3) that when opening items from any system or user-created query, the content in the Description/Steps to Reproduce/Acceptance Criteria fields is not loading to the page.

Because the blank fields are different than the database content for these fields, TFS recognizes a change, and if you save all in the query you're working through (or save the individual item without noticing), it will save the fields as blank.

You can recover content from history, of course, but this seems like a major issue.

Comment: Could you add a related screenshot for more clear description ? What's the detail mean of `blank fields are different than the database content for these fields` in your question?

Comment: Do you have the same issue when open work item through Visual Studio? Are all team projects have this issue? How about projects in different Collection? Are all users have the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, we received a response from Microsoft in the Connect forums:

Thanks for reporting this issue. There is a bug in this version where the iframe is delay loaded and there is a rare race condition where it may miss the content. The good news is the data isn't lost but you do need to revert the dirty state.

We have fixed this bug in TFS 2017. But if you can't upgrade I attached a manual workaround you can do for TFS 2015.3. Please let me know if that works for you.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

The attached file feature in Connect is broken right now so here is a link to the workaround: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AntMfPlrXI7Qx7IBgSaBNTrRhTLMGA

Steps for applying HTML field loading fix

## NOTE: THis is ONLY for TFS 2015 Update 3

1. Replace "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services_static\tfs\Dev14.M102_scripts\TFS\debug\WorkItemTracking\Scripts\TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.js" with debug\TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.js
2. Replace "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services_static\tfs\Dev14.M102_scripts\TFS\min\WorkItemTracking\Scripts\TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.js" with "min\TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.js"
3. Recycle the AppPool
4. Tell users hitting the issue to do a hard refresh

Comment: Is it the problem or the fix that is 2015.3 specific? It's now happening 100% of the time with 2015.2 and Chrome for me, after a Chrome update I guess.

Comment: This fix is in 2015.4 that was just released.